# Android Studio Java: How do I set the background of a constraint layout to be an image from a URL?

Tags: java, android, background, background-image

I am developing an app that requires me to change the background image to those provided by URLs at different times. How do I do this however? Using the following method does not work because that method takes in an integer rather than a string.

```
layout.setBackgroundResource(URL);
```

I can't use the following method from the Picasso library either since a constraint layout cannot be cast to a Target:

```
Picasso.get().load(URL).into((Target) theLayout);
```

I've also tried doing this:

```
try {
    String pictureURL = URL;
    Drawable fromURL = Drawable.createFromStream(((InputStream) new URL(pictureURL).openStream()), null);
    layout.setBackground(fromURL);
} catch(Exception j) {
    errorView.setText(j.getMessage() + "Why there");
}
```

However, my try catch is catching the error instead of having it work.

What can I do? Note that I don't want to just set the picture from the URL to be the background of an ImageView. I want to set the picture to be the background of the whole screen.

Comment: does your url live or from drawable?

Comment: @UrvishShiroya The URL is live. Also, it is not just one specific URL. This app is supposed to change backgrounds using different pictures from different URLs upon the completion of certain requirements.

Comment: i describe in answer

Answer (score 0):

You must make an attempt to incorporate this code into your project. using [Glide Android](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

1. Implement [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) in your Project.
2. Wrote down this code into your `activity.java` class

```java
Glide.with(this).load(Uri.parse("https://your_image_url/example.png")).into(new CustomTarget<Drawable>() {
    @Override
    public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Drawable resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
        layout.setBackground(resource); // here you will set your background..
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {

    }
});
```

Don't forget about adding Internet permission or some code in `manifest.xml`.

```xml
<manifest
   ...>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    
        ...

    </application>
</manifest>
```